# MySQL view no more than one of type

Tags: mysql

I am creating simple banner tracking code for a website. This works fine, but two clients dominate the random query because they have more than one banner in this location. Sometimes they will have 2 out of 3 or 3 out of 3 showing which is not what the client wants. Here is my current query for the view.

```
SELECT * FROM banners 
WHERE location like '["2"]'
AND published = '1'
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 3;
```

I have another field called client. I'd like to only choose one of their banners at a time when their location matches '["2"]'. Thanks in advance.

```
| published | location | client  | img                 |
|-----------|----------|---------|---------------------|
| 1         | ["2"]    | ClientA | /banners/image1.jpg |
| 1         | ["2"]    | ClientA | /banners/image2.jpg |
| 1         | ["2"]    | ClientA | /banners/image3.jpg |
| 1         | ["2"]    | ClientB | /banners/image4.jpg |
| 1         | ["2"]    | ClientC | /banners/image5.jpg |
| 1         | ["2"]    | ClientD | /banners/image6.jpg |
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data to your question and the output you are you looking for?

Comment: It is unfortunate that the question is being downvoted without providing constructive ideas. In the example you added, what output do you want?

Comment: And once again my comment to illustrate how ignorant people are has been removed. I want the view to load 3 banners, but only 1 per client. Thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: Got it. In the above example, client A has 3 banners. You want a random banner out of the 3 to show up for Client A, right? Client B, C and D have 1 banner each. So, your output will have only 3 records with a record missing for either Client A, B or C. Correct?

Comment: @zedfoxus That sounds pretty accurate. 3 banners total, but never more than one per client.

Comment: check out my answer below that gets you what you need.

Comment: OP - if the answer helped you, you can put closure to your question by marking it as accepted or waiting for more answers to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example:

```
create table banners (
    published int,
    location varchar(10),
    client varchar(10), 
    img varchar(100)
);

insert into banners values
(1, '["2"]', 'ClientA', '/banners/image1.jpg'),
(1, '["2"]', 'ClientA', '/banners/image2.jpg'),
(1, '["2"]', 'ClientA', '/banners/image3.jpg'),
(1, '["2"]', 'ClientB', '/banners/image4.jpg'),
(1, '["2"]', 'ClientC', '/banners/image5.jpg'),
(1, '["2"]', 'ClientD', '/banners/image6.jpg');
```

One way you can do that is using something like this:

```
-- we'll use a temporary table to store some data
-- if that table exists, let's drop it first.
-- you can change the name from banners_007 to something else

drop table if exists banners_007;

-- create that table to store data temporarily
-- store all data from banners and add a random number to each row

create table if not exists banners_007 as 
select *, rand() as randomnumber from banners;

-- get client and the lowest random number
-- and get all records for that client (you'll get 1 record per client)
-- order those clients randomly
-- get the top 3 records

select a.* from banners_007 a
inner join (

  select client, min(randomnumber) as min_rn
  from banners_007
  group by client

) b on a.client = b.client and a.randomnumber = b.min_rn
order by rand()
limit 3;
```

Example is here: https://rextester.com/ZTGED79700